# Compilation error: use of deleted function

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am working through some example code from Lazar and Penea, Mastreing Qt5: 
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Qt-5
I think I am starting to understand the code, but I am stuck with a compilation error in the method "addAlbum" in the class "AlbumModel", The offending line is

```
unique_ptr<Album> newAlbum(new Album(album));
```

which yields the error message

```
error: use of deleted function ‘Album::Album(const Album&)’

 unique_ptr<Album> newAlbum(new Album(album));
                                           ^
```

I am using CMake 3.10.2 and cpp 7.5.0. I presume the github code is correct, so this error is a bit puzzling. Although there are a lot of "use of deleted function" discussions here on stackoverflow, I have not been able to determine  the cause of the error.

Comment: The error message suggests the code is not correct . It would improve the question to include the code , see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: show us the decalration of Album, seems like one of the constructors is deleted

Comment: Obviously, the copy constructor of `Album` is deleted either implicitly (cannot be generated) or explicitly (with `= delete`).   **However, without seeing more code, we cannot give you any suggestion.**

Comment: here is the def https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Qt-5/blob/master/Chapter_03/gallery-core/Album.h my c++ isnt good enough to give the answer

Comment: Based on that definition, it would seem that `QString` is not copyable, which I very seriously doubt is the case. Can you please include the _full_ compiler output in your question? There is quite possibly some important part of the error that you've omitted.

Comment: The error turned out to steam from the class Album, where I had experimented with declared an array based on a template. So problem solved. Thanks.